# Jaccard Coefficient in R

Tags: r, similarity

I have some trouble understanding what seems to be pretty easy calculation.

I understand Jaccard coefficient is intersection(A,B)/union(A,B), so how come this is true?

```
> sets::gset_similarity(c("1","2"), c("1","2","3"), "Jaccard")
[1] 1
```

Isn't it `2/3`?

Comment: That is not the correct definition for Jaccard distance. Doing the operation you suggest also doesn't return 2/3.

Comment: Also don't forget about cardinality. That's part of the calculation as well. You can see that if you just run the function name (no `()`) so that you see how it works.

Comment: @lmkirvan Sorry, why is it not 2/3?

Comment: You might be interested in the vegdist function the vegan package for dissimilarity indices (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vegan/docs/vegdist).

Comment: @Imkirvan - seems fine to me, if you don't take it absolutely literally - `A <- 1:2; B <- 1:3; length(intersect(A,B)) / length(union(A,B))` is 2/3rds - intersect/union sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you pass it actual `set` data (see `?sets::set`):

```
gset_similarity(set("1","2"), set("1","2","3"), "Jaccard") 
#[1] 0.6666667
```

Or

```
gset_similarity(as.set(c("1","2")), as.set(c("1","2","3")), "Jaccard")
#[1] 0.6666667
```

...if you have existing vectors and need to convert them.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need to read about `set` data.